# Planet where most children are clones of their mother. Non clones are called Vars and discriminated against

Tags: story-identification, novel, clones, planets

The planet has mostly medieval technology. I think a train might have been mentioned at one point. I do not remember whether they know they are descended from humans from Earth.

They were genetically engineered by their anscestors who believed it was desirable to slow down the rate of evolution of humanity.

The vast majority of children born on this planet are female and genetically identical to their mothers.

Non-idential children are called Vars and discriminated against. One such girl comments about the injustice that all boys are Vars but nobody holds it against them.

The two protagonists are not clones of their mother but identical twins. They leave home, are thrown out of their birth family on reaching adulthood. I remember each being given a stout pair of boots plus another practical gift to help them in their new lives. They are told they should be grateful for these gifts as few clone families are so generous to their varient daughters.

The twins plan to pretend to be two members of a clone family to avoid discrimination. At one point in the story, one of the girls is imprisoned. She is given four books to read to avoid boredem.

One of the books is a classic of literature, over a hundred years old. The book is about young twin girls pretending to belong to a noble clone family.

The names of the twins in the classic book are the same names given to the twin protagonists. It was a cruel joke their birth family had played on them. Had they gone through with their plan to pretend to be clones, any educated person would see right through them when they heard their given names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [*Glory Season*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/834670.Glory_Season) by David Brin.

> In Glory Season, David Brin depicts a world with an intensely
> matriarchal society. The majority of the population of Stratos
> consists of female clones, "sparked" in winter by male sperm, but
> genetic copies of their mothers. Men and "variant" girls are born in
> summer. Designed this way the founders of Stratos, this society is
> supposedly pastoral and stable, with the clones running the show and
> the "vars" (men and variant girls) struggling to fit in wherever they
> can.
>
> [image]